# How is Brownian motion predictable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Could someone please explain how Brownian motion is predictable? My understanding is that a predictable process is one that depends on information up to time t say but not t itself, therefore W_t has to be observed at time t to determine its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brownian motion is continuous in time so you can determine the value of $W_t$ as a limit from the left: $W_t=\lim_{s\rightarrow t^-}W_s$.